# Does it make any difference whether SAVE is used as a seperate statement, for a DATA-initialised variable?

Tags: fortran, static-variables

Is this

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(4), SAVE :: foo
DATA foo / 3, 14, 15, 93 /
```

equivalent to

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(4) :: foo
DATA foo / 3, 14, 15, 93 /
SAVE foo
```

Comment: A `save` statement says an entity has the `save` attribute, regardless of initialization.  But I don't understand the question, in that I can't see why you think there may be a difference in the way attributes are specified.  Can you give your thinking?

Comment: In the final way `foo` is a named constant, which it isn't in the others.  Are you asking for the implications of being a named constant rather than a variable (albeit one which doesn't change value during program execution)?

Comment: And, of course, we don't need the `save` attribute to be specified by the attribute list or attribute statement: it's implied by the explicit initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the declaration statements is just an older way of specifying attributes.

You can as well do shorter

```
 INTEGER, SAVE :: foo(4) = [3, 14, 15, 93]
```

or even

```
 INTEGER :: foo(4) = [3, 14, 15, 93]
```

as the `SAVE` attribute is implied by the initialization.

It is all the same.

In the other direction you can put the `DIMENSION` part into a separate statement (very old style)

```
INTEGER foo
SAVE foo
DIMENSION foo(4)
DATA foo / 3, 14, 15, 93 /
```

the meaning is again the same, it is just longer.

The `parameter` is different, that is a named constant, not a variable.

Comment: I removed the bit about PARAMETER, suppose it better belongs in a separate question.

Comment: What would you say is the _recommended_ style?

Comment: In my opinion `integer, save :: foo(4) = [3, 14, 15, 93] `. The `data` statement is old-style and it is sometimes better to remind the reader of the `save` statement even if it is implied. Depends on the expected experience of the readers of the code, but it is a common pitfall.